# How to mock final class in java by using EasyMock?- Junit test

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have final class and with constructor for that...

I have problem to mock this class. I came to know that i cannot use EasyMock for final class. But in my project i should use easymock only. Is there a way to mock this class? Can you please anyone help me in this?

```
//A a = createMock(A.class);//IllegalException occuring while running this test case


For example :

final class A {

private int a;
  A(int a){
this.a = a;
}

}
```

Comment: You could extract it's interface, then use the interface everywhere, then mock the new interface.

Comment: Why is the class final in the first place?

Comment: its client code as final class.So i cannot change.Due to that i am struggling

Answer (score 8):

It's impossible to mock a final class with pure EasyMock. You'll have to add in something like [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/), which integrates well with EasyMock. Or you write a test that doesn't require mocking of a final class.

Comment: `PowerMock.mockStatic(MyFinalClass);` is what I'm doing, and I get an error which says "Cannot subclass final class ". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: but I didn't find support from powerMock with java11 do you have suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is that if your final class implements any interface (considering that the interface includes the methods you need to use in your test), you can always create instances of another class that implements that same interface and use this as the mock or use [dynamic proxies](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html).

The problem is that sometimes finding workarounds to requirements will exponentially multiply the work required to do something when you already know that tools like PowerMock are out there.

Comment: "you can always create instances of another class that implements that same interface and use this as the mock" - If you have the interface, then why not mock the interface? That's the point. No need to create a stub implementation if you're just wanting to use a mock.